# Regular Expression That Doesn't Skip Over Text

Tags: regex, grouping, matching

I know my question isn't worded that well, but I couldn't think of another way to state it. Imagine I have the follow text that I want to do a Regex match on:

```
Some random text here <STARTTAG1>text to match<ENDTAG1> some more 
random text <STARTTAG2>text to match<ENDTAG2>  more random text 
Some random text here <STARTTAG1>I don't want this text to match<ENDTAG1> some more 
random text more random text 
Some random text here <STARTTAG1>text to match<ENDTAG1> some more 
random text <STARTTAG2>text to match<ENDTAG2>  more random text
```

Here's the regex I'm currently using:

```
<STARTTAG1>(?<text1>.*?)<ENDTAG1>?.*?<STARTTAG2>(?<text2>.*?)<ENDTAG2>
```

If you run that regex on the supplied text, it doesn't match the text in the correct pairs. I want it to ignore any STARTTAG1/ENDTAG1 matches if they don't have a STARTTAG2/ENDTAG2 before it encounters another STARTTAG1/ENDTAG1.

Any help would be appreciated. If my explanation isn't very good, please just run the regex on the text and you'll see what I mean (hopefully).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subpattern `.*?` in:

```
<STARTTAG1>(?<text1>.*?)<ENDTAG1>?.*?<STARTTAG2>(?<text2>.*?)<ENDTAG2>
                                  ^ ^
                             here |_|
```

is matching the *middle* `TAG1` that should be ignored. So we need to match any character except `<STARTTAG1>`. We can achieve that by a kind of *loop* checking each character is not followed by the tag using a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(?:(?!<STARTTAG1>).)*?
```

That way, it prevents that subpattern to match the *middle* tag. However, as it now fails, the regex engine will backtrack, and the previous subpattern:

```
(?<text1>.*?)
```

will try to match the text:

```
I don't want this text to match<ENDTAG1> some more 
random text more random text 
Some random text here <STARTTAG1>text to match<ENDTAG1>
```

We could use the same approach, but we could also use an [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) to prevent backtracking.

```
(?><STARTTAG1>(?<text1>.*?)<ENDTAG1>)
```

**Regex**

```
(?><STARTTAG1>(?<text1>.*?)<ENDTAG1>)(?:(?!<STARTTAG1>).)*?<STARTTAG2>(?<text2>.*?)<ENDTAG2>
```

- Modes: global + singleline

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ2zB9/1)</kbd>

Comment: Beautiful! Works perfectly. Thanks for the explanation too, it helps me understand what is actually happening.